# How to get original custom taxonomy slug after the slug has been rewritten?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, ajax, terms

I'm writing ajax handling for a theme. I'm trying to get term and taxonomy slugs from a link I click. The link is being passed with jQuery to PHP for further processing.

Let's say my custom taxonomy is "tax" and term within that taxonomy is "abc":

---

Example:

link I click looks like this - `https://localhost/test/tax/abc/`.

It's being parsed with `wp_parse_url()`. After parsing URL and fiddling with it a little I get "abc" as my term slug and "tax" as my taxonomy slug.

Then I use `get_term_by( 'slug', 'abc', 'tax' )` and get term data this way. Simple.

---

Problem occurs when taxonomy slug is rewritten.

Example 2:

Let's say I've rewritten my custom taxonomy slug "tax" with `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tax-rewrite' )`, passed to `register_taxonomy()`.

Now link I click looks like this: `https://localhost/test/tax-rewrite/abc/`.

When I pass it to `get_term_by()` as "tax-rewrite" it fails because `get_term_by()` needs original taxonomy slug which in this case is still "tax", but I can't get it from the link anymore.

Is there a way to get original taxonomy slug from rewritten link, get original taxonomy slug from rewrite slug, or any other way to get term data for my ajax handling?

Best regards, Dan.

Comment: What AJAX handling are you doing? Is there a reason you're trying to parse this from the URL? Why not just send the taxonomy as part of the AJAX request?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason, URL is readily available in website's `wp_nav_menu()`. Actually I could get menu item ID with jQuery and then play a bit with `get_post_meta( $menu_item_id, '_menu_item_object_id', true );` to get post ID or term ID associated with that particular menu item, but I'm trying to bring down the amount of code to necessary minimum. Hence use of link URL of main nav menu seems to be a reliable option.

Comment: Why not just make the AJAX request directly to that URL and pull the HTML out of the response? That’s a common pattern and I believe jQuery even has helped functions for it. Then there’s no backend code at all. Otherwise you’re going to be wasting a lot of time implementing routing functionality that already exists.

Comment: @JacobPeattie And with pure jQuery how server would know what content to serve to the browser?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It will just return the HTML for the page...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I'm aware of, with PHP served content, you need PHP to fetch that content from database and send the data back to JavaScript. With just jQuery or pure JS that would work with static HTML but not PHP, am I wrong here?

Comment: PHP is still serving the page. If you send a request with jQuery to https://localhost/test/tax-rewrite/abc/ you’ll get the exact same result as if you visit it in the browser.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I tried sending request to the specific address instead of WordPress Ajax, as you suggested, and it actualy gets the data. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get any scripts to work with newly loaded content. Have you got any idea how to achieve that?